# Corelate Rating and Confidence

Tags: probability

Imagine a one evaluation list composed by two variables: Rating and confidence.
Rating and confidence are in the scale of 0-100. 
For a specific combination of Rating and confidence i need to achieve a single value that represents both numbers. The scale of the new value can be 0-100 or other 0-1000 or 0-10000, etc.

Is this possible to do without distortion of the meaning? Is there a formula to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is something like $10^4*R+C$ what you want? I'm not sure I understood the question, but if you are given $10^4*R+C$ then you know $R$ and $C$

Comment: i dont understand it. you are adding the confidence to Rating multiplied to 10 at 4th power? Imagine this. Rating 70 with confidence 10. You would say the real value is below 50(empiric) but if you have Rating 55 with 90 confidence than we could consider that the "real" value is near Rating 55 maybe 60 or so...